# If $f$ is bounded, differentiable and satisfies the inequality, does there exist $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

Let $f:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ be a function. Suppose that $f$ is bounded, differentiable and satisfies the following inequality: $$f(x)f'(x)\geq \sin(x)\text{ for all }x\in[0,\infty).$$
Does there exist $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x)$?

I suppose that the statement is false since I don't see how the inequality will help us prove the limit existence. However, I have not found out any counterexample yet.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take $f(x) = \sqrt{3-2\cos(x)}$.
Then $f$ is bounded, differentiable and
$$
f(x)\,f'(x) = \frac{1}{2} (f(x)^2)' = (\tfrac{3}{2}-\cos(x))' = \sin(x)
$$
but $f$ has no limit at $+\infty$.

Comment: Thanks!! Would you tell me how you found this function?

Comment: Yes. The first step is to replace $f\,f'$ by $g' = (f^2/2)'$. Then solve
$g' = \sin$
with the constraint that $g$ is strictly positive ;) Of course you can replace $3$ by any $C > 2$.

Comment: I get it. Thanks!!

Comment: Great example...